# Зачем возвращать null?

Tags: php, yii

Зачем возвращать здесь **null**, если **$language** === **null**, значит там **null**.

```
    if ( $language === null ) {
        return null;
    }else{
        return $language;
    }
```

То есть если там не **null**, то мы возвращает язык, иначе **null**, но зачем? Ведь если он там есть, он и так возвратиться как **null**...

Или это 2 разных вида **null**-ов?

Нельзя ли проще написать:

```
return $language;
```

Или же в первом случае будет:
Возвратит объект **lang** со свойствами **url**:null, **default**:null, а с проверкой возвратит просто **null**?

Comment: судя по всему это просто пример говнокода, и лучше было бы написать именно 

    return $language;

разумеется, никаких двух разных null нетю null он в и Африке null

Comment: Вся эта конструкция действительно заменяется простым `return $language;`. Иногда `return null;` делается для того, чтобы подчеркнуть, что метод "смог все, что мог и вернул ничего", но это не тот случай.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятнее всего там было что-то другое, это что-то изменилось, но программисты - народ ленивый (по себе знаю :)), поэтому не убрали или оставили на будущее и забыли, ибо не критично это.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if(!emtpy($language) {
      return $language
   }
```

Можешь так оптимизировать, если пока не видно, для чего это было сделано. Функция [empty()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.empty.php) проверяет, пуста ли переменная.